# Laravel get localization through variable/value

Tags: laravel, localization

In `lang/en/messages.php` i have the following key/value:

`"producer" => "Producer",`

A `$user->role` holds the value `Producer` in database.

For example `{{ __($user->role) }}` doesn't work. Is it possible to take the translation based on the value and not key?

I know that `{{ __("messages.producer") }}` will work - but it is not what I need.

Comment: You can use `{{ __("messages.{$user->role}") }}` or you can write a custom helper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the array of a language file like this:

```
$messages = Lang::get('messages')
```

After that, you can search for the key by the value using `array_search`:

```
$key = array_search($user->role, $messages);
```

Then you can use the key for the translation:

```
{{ __("messages." . $key) }}
```

You might want to create a helper to implement this :).

Comment: Thank you, your answer works great! However, i decided to change my DB and save the key than the value...

Comment: Nice, you're welcome! Good decision, it makes things easier.